# Is there another way in Unity3d to access device camera?

Tags: c#, c++, unity-game-engine, android-ndk, shared-libraries

In Unity3d, in order to access the device camera there is one class to do that : **WebCamTexture**

Is there any other way to access it for all platforms, using native plugins for example ?

Answer (score 0):

based on unity documentation, it can be used in any platform.([HERE](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/WebCamTexture-ctor.html))

> Note: using webcam texture on Android requires a device running
>   Honeycomb (Android 3.0) or later.

but you can use an old asset called NatCam